# Error mounting 16.10 with non-zero exit status 32: mount: Bad message

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, 16.10

After installing ubuntu 16.10 in dualboot with ubuntu 14.04 (which is my prime os) i've suddenly encountered this kind of something:

> Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at
>   /media/nerbellion/4d28c2ff-7649-4dd1-b423-3a48b5c695de: Command-line
>   `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdb1"
>   "/media/nerbellion/4d28c2ff-7649-4dd1-b423-3a48b5c695de"' exited with
>   non-zero exit status 32: mount: Bad message

`/dev/sdb1` as `/home`

> Error mounting /dev/sdb9 at
>   /media/nerbellion/a7a0a95e-8d8f-4486-8d8b-ae4f09aa11e2: Command-line
>   `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdb9"
>   "/media/nerbellion/a7a0a95e-8d8f-4486-8d8b-ae4f09aa11e2"' exited with
>   non-zero exit status 32: mount: Bad message

`/dev/sdb9` as `/root`

What is the solution to this? It's happened after the installation.

By the way, `/dev/sdb` is my secondary external hdd, not the one, containing main os - 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

*Upd*: Using [this helpful answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/808650/354766)
i've tried to update **fsck**:

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/e2fsprogs/e2fsprogs/v1.43.1/e2fsprogs-1.43.1.tar.gz
tar xzf e2fsprogs-1.43.1.tar.gz
cd e2fsprogs-1.43.1
./configure # <== if this step fail, check the config.log file, it could just be that you are missing the "libc6-dev" package on your system
make
cd e2fsck/
./e2fsck
```

Then done as follows:

```
./e2fsck -p -b 32768 /dev/sdb1
./e2fsck -p -b 32768 /dev/sdb9
./e2fsck -p -v /dev/sdb1
./e2fsck -p -v /dev/sdb9
```

Fascinating, now i can access the both devices as mediums just fine.
Apologize for cause the commotion with my lack of expertise here in the first place.