# 16.04 updated e2fsck but virt-builder command is still using the older version

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm running 16.04 on an Intel Nuc trying to setup a virtual environment.  My virt-builder command fails with this error:

```
virt-resize: error: libguestfs error: resize2fs: e2fsck 1.42.13
(17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1 has unsupported feature(s): metadata_csum
e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!
```

I upgraded e2fsck to version 1.43.1 and I verified with a *e2fsck -V* command but for some reason everytime I run my virt-builder command it still using the 1.42.13 version of e2fsck.  How can I either remove the old version of e2fsck or at least ensure that virt-builder uses the newer version?

Comment: Hi @dreed47 your base e2fsck version suggests you are on Xenial, but there is no newer e2fsprogs package for Xenial than 1.42.13-1ubuntu1. "How exactly" did you upgrade to 1.43.1 - maybe therein lies the solution to resolve your issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ext4 broken file system on ubuntu 14.04.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747656/ext4-broken-file-system-on-ubuntu-14-04-4)