# e2fsck error installing 16.04 alongside 20.04

Tags: dual-boot

I'm using Acer Aspire V5-573PG. Currently I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 and I want to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 in order to use ROS Kinetic Kame. Every time i boot with 16.04 the installing wizard continues till the partitioning window, but when I select the partition and tries to install the OS, it gives an error msg saying, e2fsck: Get a newer version of e2fsck!

My question is "Should I install the older version first and then install the newer version?" or is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: They should both be installed either BIOS mode or UEFI mode. Use the "Something else" install option. They can share a /home folder as long as they are the same "Flavour". Select the root drive for Bootloader location, not a partition. Try installing the older version first.

Comment: I would create / partition with 20.04.1 and just install 16.04.6 into that partition. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/747656/after-a-power-failure-unable-to-mount-the-drive-get-a-newer-version-of-e2fsck

Answer (score 0):

You should install Docker and use the ROS images available ([here](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros)). I've done a good bit of ROS work and would **highly** recommend learning some Docker basics for this stuff! The exact OS incompatibility issue you're describing is why I use docker.